# Restart with PM2 API, restarts also the script self, when running in PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, pm2

I want to make a script in Javascript which controlls PM2 via the PM2 API, and also runs in PM2.

**pm2.js**

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

setTimeout(() => {
  restartProcess('client');
}, 2000); //After 2 seconds restart the 'client' process

function restartProcess(name) {

  pm2.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(2);
    }
    console.log ("restarting ",name)
    pm2.restart(name);

  pm2.disconnect;  
  })
  
}
```

When I run `pm2.js` only in the terminal, this works okay.
But when I run `pm2.js` inside PM2, the script keeps looping.
I checked the uptime of the processes, it seems that not only `client` restarts but also `pm2.js` itself restarts, and after 2 seconds again, and again, and again...

If I'm lookings at `pm2 logs pm2` I see there in de `stdout` the pm2 list table. Which I don't see if I run `pm2.js` from the terminal.

I don't understand why this happens, and is there a workarround to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that?

> PM2 is a daemon process manager that will help you manage and keep your application online 24/7

Please check the [official document](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) first. PM2 was designed to manage long-running tasks, somethings like a web server. If the web server crashes or exits by any reasons, pm2 will interfere and wake it up again. That's the default behavior.

Your pm2.js just run in a short time (2 seconds) then exit. So if you start it with PM2, it will be started again and again...

There is no reason to run that script inside PM2. If you still want, then run it with `--no-autorestart` flag.

Comment: The 2 seconds timeout is just for test purposes, I use socket.io to connect to pm2.js. In other words: I want to make a webpage GUI were I can control my PM2 processes, like starting, stopping and restarting.

Comment: Then just do it, create a long running task and trigger pm2.restart() only when getting events from your webpage. Not a script like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can send SIGKILL to your service, then PM2 will start it again.

```
pm2.connect((err) => {
    pm2.sendSignalToProcessName('SIGKILL', name, (e, p) => {
        pm2.disconnect();
    });
});
```